# Solidity: State Mutability Warning

Tags: solidity, remix

This line of code changes state when a new owner is set, but remix still wants to me to mark the declaration with `view`, which reads from the contract.

Why is that?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

 function setOwner(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner {
        require(_newOwner != address(0), "invalid address");
        owner == _newOwner;
    }
```

View causes me to not be able to properly set (change) state.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error on solidity's side look, at your owner variable change :

```
owner == _newOwner;
```

I believe you meant to write :

```
 owner = _newOwner;
```

This meant your function was actually not changing the state in any way. So requiring it to be set to view is a perfectly valid recommendation.

Comment: This is correct! I can't believe I missed that. Accepted, but don't have 15 points yet!